# The order of construction of variables that are not same compilation unit

Tags: c++, g++

As you alreay know, the order of constructions of variables that are both defined outside of a function and different compilation units is not fixed. With this understanding, i devised simple codes that i think have to crash while running. However, It just didn't. Here are the codes.

```
/* table.h */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class table {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    table(table& t) {
        a = t.a;
        b = t.b;
    }
    void print(void) {
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << b << endl;
    }
};

/* f1.cpp */
#include "./table.h"
extern table t2;
table t1 = t2;

/* f2.cpp */
#include "./table.h"
extern table t1;
table t2 = t1;

/* core.cpp */
#include "./table.h"
extern table t1;
extern table t2;
int main(void) {
    t1.print();
    t2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the t1 and t2 are referring each other. Although we're not sure which one will be allocated first, it is evident that one is to access the other that are not allocated, which is a total disaster. It's so weird it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to crash - it is just undefined behavior. You never initialize the member variables with real values, so the output will be garbage no matter what order they are initialized.

As they are global variables, their memory space is reserved/allocated at the very beginning of the execution. The problem is the order in which the constructors are called. If you reference the object before it has been constructed, the member variables will have whatever value happened to be there already.

Comment: I think the question is not much about the member variable's value. It more about initialization of one object depending on the other and vice-versa.

Comment: @Mahesh:  They are both global variables, so the memory will already be allocated ... it will just be garbage data.

Comment: @ZacHowland, will it be garbage or will it be guaranteed to be zeros? I honestly can't remember.

Comment: In either case it would be garbage (even if they are default-initialized to 0) as the variables would have no real data in them yet are being used in another instance's copy-constructor.

Comment: Are local variables also be allocated before initialization?

Comment: @isbae93 Local variables are allocated when the program flow encounters them. You cannot have this problem with local variables, as they are initialized in the order you do it.

Comment: The result of my program presents four zeros. How can it be possible? The a and b are not static members. Why are they zeros?

Comment: Global variables are statically initialized to all-zero before dynamic initializers ever run.

Comment: @isbae93 I cannot remember for sure, but it may be guaranteed that the memory behind global variables is zero'd at the beginning. See Zac Howland's comment.

Comment: Oh... I'm sorry. The class itself is global. That's why they have zeros before copy constructor!

Comment: I'm not even sure that it's undefined behavior.  Because the variables are static, `a` and `b` are guaranteed to be `0` initialized before any constructors are run.

Comment: @JamesKanze It's well-defined to use a class before it's been constructed?

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm not sure.  It's well defined to use its address, and in this case, you're accessing a simple member variable.  I'm really not sure.  (I know that from within the constructor, you can access the data members before they have been initialized, provided the instance is static.)

Answer (score 1):

The initialization of global objects is not ordered across translation units.

The typical way to ensure that an object is initialized before use is to wrap it into a function like this:

**myfoo.h:**

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo & myFoo();
```

**myfoo.cc:**

```
#include "myfoo.h"

Foo & myFoo()
{
    static Foo impl;
    return impl;
}
```

Everyone who needs the global object includes `myfoo.h` and refers to the global object as `myFoo()`.

If you try this approach on your problem (suitably modified to account for the initializers), you will see that your problem is ill-defined, as you will enter the same static initialization more than once.

Answer (score 1):

> i think have to crash while running

No; it has (borderline) undefined behaviour, but there's no requirement for undefined behaviour to cause a crash. If there were, then the behaviour would be defined.

> it is evident that one is to access the other that are not allocated

They have been allocated, just not (dynamically) initialised. The storage for static objects is allocated, and zero-initialised, in the static initialisation phase before any user code is run. Then, during dynamic initialisation, each object is initialised using the zero-valued memory of the other.

> It's so weird it works fine

Formally, accessing the objects' values before initialisation gives undefined behaviour. In practise, you will simply access the zero-valued memory with no indication of the error.